# Transform a matrix so that it can be plotted with heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a matrix that I want to visualize in heatmap, with ggplot, such as geom_tile in R. The data are current in the format of

```
   I   II
A  1   2
B  3   4
```

However, to use ggplot, I need to transform this matrix into a data frame in the format like this:

```
Var1   Var2   Value
A      I      1
A      II     2
B      I      3
B      II     4
```

How do I transform the matrix to this format so that I can use ggplot? I don't want visualization package such as gplot because it seems a lot slower. Thanks.

Comment: `melt` from `reshape2` does exactly this

Comment: @Patronus Could you explain more? I and II are column names, and A and B are row names. When I use melt(), I get only one column for variable and one column for value, and row names disappear. It says something like "No id variables; using all as measure variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the code how you create data? I try to code myself, melt just works fine.

```
a = matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), 2, dimnames = list(c('A', 'B'), c('I', 'II')))
melt(a)
```

This is what I get:

```
  Var1 Var2 value
1    A    I     1
2    B    I     3
3    A   II     2
4    B   II     4
```

Comment: After I transform my data frame into matrix, it works. It seems that melt() cannot handle data frame.

Comment: @S.Wang In fact melt can handle both data frame and matrix. If you want rownames as id.var, melt can capture rownames from a matrix, but for a data frame, I believe you have to create a variable for rownames, then use argument id.var to refer it. For more details to melt a data frame, try ?melt.data.frame

Comment: @S.Wang you said in your question "I have a matrix"